# How would I be able to get a game over screen using the pause function?

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, collision-detection

I am having problems with my snake game, when the snake collides with itself it draws a "game over" image in the background, but only while it's colliding with itself. I want it to behave like the pause function, so that as soon as the snake collides with itself it draws an image on the screen and stops the game play. And then how would you be able to restart or to quit the game?

I just have this for the detection at the moment:

```
if (snakeHeadRectangle.Intersects(snakeBodyRectangleArray[bodyNumber]))
            {

              spriteBatch.Draw(textureGameOver, gameOverPosition, Color.White);
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a boolean variable `isGameRunning` which is set to `true` if the game is on.
Update the game only when this variable is true.
After collision, you can set this to `false`.

For more functionality you can have more states like

```
enum GameStates
{ Running, Paused, Over, WaitingForKeystrokeToBegin }
```

instead of just `true` and `false`.

To restart the game, create an `Initialize()` function to reset the settings.